# Rewrite URL with masking from HTTP to HTTPS site (on a different server) are certs needed on first server?

Tags: https, mod-rewrite, proxy

I have a *:80 virtual host in Apache 2.2.15 which is just a bunch of URL rewrites like:

```
ServerAlias foo.bar biz.baz tit.tat
RewriteRule / http://somesite.com (R=301,L)

ServerAlias differentsite.com example.it
RewriteRule ....
```

I want to do a masked URL rewrite so babysnakes.com goes to https://dancingfool.com/moms.php

I tried using mod_rewrite with P flag and I tried mod_proxy and then realized it doesn't handle SSL proxying, that mod_ssl should handle. What I am not clear on is whether I can do SSLProxyEngine in a non SSL vhost config (no certs defined etc).

Comment: In your example, there is no redirect to a `HTTPS`, is this just a typo?

Comment: No, my example just shows what the rest of the conf file looks like, but you can assume that I would basically like to use that syntax if possible, but with the destination being HTTPS, this is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Are you wanting to Proxy (transparent) or do a 301 redirect?  A 301 redirect will change the URL.

Comment: Proxy is fine, I just want a masked URL rewrite, whatever works.

Comment: Just to point out that this is generally a **terrible idea**. Most sites enable SSL to protect their users. By doing so, you're effectively downgrading the level of security they have when accessing that site.

Comment: @Bruno I think you are misunderstanding the question, I am talking about Redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS, not the other way around.

Comment: I wasn't sure, since you were talking about `P` (a proxy rewrite) and the only answer so far suggests a `P` rewrite. If what you want is a redirect, it's different indeed, but you haven't used the word "redirect" before that last comment. You're also talking about a "masked URL rewrite", which sounds more like a proxy than a redirect. If you want the user to have secure access to the target site, you can't hide its URL from them.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `SSLProxyEngine On` to make the proxy work via SSL.

```
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^babysnakes.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ https://dancingfool.com/moms.php [P,L]
```

I did a quick test of proxy requests to an SSL page using the [P] flag and it worked for me. (different domains though)

Comment: Don't forget `SSLProxyCheckPeerName on` (and other `SSLProxyCheck*` directives) if it's not enabled by default in your version (e.g. Apache 2.2), even if the whole idea isn't really secure anyway.